# Erlang Implementation of A Star Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, erlang, a-star

I need an Erlang implementation of the A* search algorithm. 
Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2008/10/first-refactoring-of-star-in-erlang.html